# Force Nexus to update/create index for repository

Tags: nexus

I have added a remote repository http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external/ as a proxy repository to my Nexus instance.

Nexus shows the index as empty.

Any dependencies I try to get from Nexus will fail. I tried update/rebuild index but that doesn't seem to do much.

What is the correct way to build the index using Nexus?

Answer (score 1):

This repository does not publish search indexes (search indexes are an optional repository feature).

Search indexes are not used for artifact retrieval, they are only used to support interactive search in clients such as m2Eclipse and Nexus.  The proxy will work without search indexes.  As artifacts are downloaded from the remote they will be added to the local search indexes in Nexus.

Comment: IntelliJ using Maven 3, however, does use the index to search where to download artifacts from, instead of trying to download the artifact directly.